# For which rings can elements be written as a finite product of irreducible elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> For which rings $A$ can elements be written as a finite product of irreducible elements?

I feel like this is true for almost all rings I have ever encountered, but when do I know that I can write any nonzero nonunit element of $A$ as a finite product of irreducible elements? (I am not assuming the product is unique here.)

In particular, if $A$ is an affine $k$-algebra can I always do this? ($k$ algebraically closed field)

Thanks!

Comment: For a Noetherian ring the answer is yes.

Comment: How would one go about proving it? Does it follow easily from the definition?

Comment: @Johnny For a rough sketch, factoring out elements successively gives you an ascending chain of principal ideals. When the chain stabilizes the element is irreducible.